# Perl: add character to begin of a line

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I want to add a " character to the begin of every line in a text file. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: If perl is not mandatory I would suggest using sed: `sed -i 's/^/"/' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`perl -p -e 's/^/"/' myfile` should do it!

```
$ cat myfile 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ perl -p -e 's/^/"/' myfile
"0
"1
"2
"3
"4
"5
"6
"7
"8
"9
"10
```

Comment: Or `perl -pe '$_ = qq{"$_}' myfile`

Comment: Thanks, the /^/ indicate the begin of a line?

Comment: @Adrian: yes, `^` is the beginning of line, and `$` then end.

Answer (score 2):

Another couple of suggestions:

just in the shell:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
while read -r line; do printf '"%s\n' "$line"; done < filename > "$tmp" &&
mv "$tmp" filename
```

ed:

```
ed describes.sql.bak <<'END'
1,$s/^/"/
w
q
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider one of these ways:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/^/"/' inputfile.txt
```

Edit file in place, saves a backup in "inputfile.txt.bak".

```
perl -pe 's/^/"/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Use shell redirection to print the output to a new file.