# Add number of white spaces at begin of each line (within one string)

Tags: regex, perl

This is kind of a follow-up question to [Perl: add character to begin of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847443/perl-add-character-to-begin-of-a-line).

**The Situation**
Within an existing Perl script I've got a reasonable long string `$str` containing an unknown number of line breaks (`\n`). There is now line break at the end of the string.

```
$str = "Hello\nWorld.\nHow is it going?"
```

**The Problem**
I would like to add a certain (constant) number of white spaces at the beginning of each line within the string: (in this case 3)

```
$str = "   Hello\n   World.\n   How is it going?"
```

**First approach**
My first approach was the following RegEx

```
$str =~ s/(.*?\n)/   \1/g;
```

And to cache the last line, which is not terminated by a new line

```
$str =~ s/(.*)\n(.*)?$/\1\n   \2/g;
```

**The Wish**
First. The above lines work perfectly and do exactly what I intended. But. I know, RegEx are powerful and thus I'm pretty sure, one can do the same thing in just one short RegEx. Unfortunately, I was yet not able to achieve this. (It's very likely, that I'm thinking way too complex.)

So, what possibilities do one have for this problem?
Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Match the *beginning* of each line instead, perhaps:

```
$str =~ s/^/   /mg;
```

Notes from [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers):

- `^` - matches the beginning of a line.
- `m` - treat the string multiple lines so `^` and `$` match line start and ends anywhere in the string, not just the start and end overall.
- `g` - global - apply to every match found.

Comment: Thank's a lot. The flag `m` was the missing key. Additional question not stated above: Is there an abbreviation for multiple spaces? I do not want to type out (or hard code) 5 or more spaces.

Comment: @T.K. - You could do something like: `my $indent = ' ' x 5;
$str =~ s/^/$indent/mg;`  That will assign five spaces to `$indent` and use it for the substitution.

Comment: That would be one option, yes. But is it not possible to use the 'multiplicators' of RegEx: `{n}`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the OP meant that the newline characters are part of the string? If this is the case then this regex :

```
$subject =~ s/((?<=^)|(?<=\\n))/    /g;
```

Should work.

**Explanation :**

```
"
(              # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
                  # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      (?<=           # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
         ^              # Assert position at the beginning of the string
      )
   |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      (?<=           # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
         \\n             # Match a line feed character
      )
)
"
```

See it working [here](http://ideone.com/Tfhj4).

Comment: This is wired. In my script this is not working. It only adds the white spaces at the very begin of the whole string, but not after each newline.

Comment: @T.K. Well you saw it working right? :) So I mean if you just copy it is should work. I don't know what's wrong in your case :)