# perl command error

Tags: string, perl, file

I am using the information I found on this post

[Perl: add character to begin of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847443/perl-add-character-to-begin-of-a-line)

to create this perl command (I need to add a |1 to the end of each string)

```
perl -p -e 's/$/|1/' C:\Users\Leslie\TABLE0212201314402-out.csv > C:\Users\Leslie\new.csv
```

and I get the error:

*'1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*

Do I need to do something to my |1 so that it works? Thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead :

```
perl -p -e "s/$/|1/" C:\Users\Leslie\TABLE0212201314402-out.csv > C:\Users\Leslie\new.csv
```

Note the use of double quotes instead of single quotes for the Windows command shell.